# Formulario com Bootstrap não passa POST

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou fazendo um formulário de login, estava funcionando perfeitamente, mas daí resolvi incorporar alguns elementos do `Bootstrap` para ficar visualmente mais agradável. Depois disso, meu form parou de enviar o método POST. Alguém que possa me ajudar?

```
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" Style="width: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
             <h3 class="panel-title">Entre com seu usuario e senha</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form action="index.php" method="post" target="_self" id="login">
                    <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> 
                        <input name="user" type="text" autofocus required="required" form="login" size="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> 
                        <input name="senha" type="password" required="required" form="login" size="25" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua senha">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <?php if (!empty($_GET[ 'falhalogin'])) { echo "<p>Usuário (".$_POST[ 'user']. ") ou senha (".$_POST[ 'senha']. ") inválido.</p>"; } ?></p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" id="entrar" form="login" value="Login" action="index.php" class="btn btn-default">
                </form>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parou de funcionar significa o que? não chega no index.php?

Comment: Esse `$_GET['falhalogin']` vem da onde? parece ser o problema, pelo menos no seu form não tem nada de get.

Comment: Achei o problema aqui... quando eu estava "incorporando" o template que peguei do bootstrap acabei apagando parte do meu PHP... daí a página estava fazendo um redirecionamento para ela mesma.. neste processo eu perdia o POST.... corrigi e o form voltou a rodar redondo!!! obrigado galera!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não tem nada a ver com o Bootstrap. O problema deve ser por que você está colocando um parágrafo dentro do outro:

```
<p>                    
<?php    
     if (!empty($_GET['falhalogin'])) { 
              echo "<p>Usuário (".$_POST['user'].") ou senha (".$_POST['senha'].") inválido.</p>";
                }
                ?>

                </p>
```

Tire um dos `<p>` `</p>` (ou que está no PHP ou o que está no HTML) que deve funcionar.

E um dos fechamentos do seu parágrafo está fora de `</form>`, volte-o para dentro:

```
<p>

                        <input   type="submit" id="entrar" form="login" value="Login" action="index.php" class="btn btn-default">
                </form>
                </p>
```

Comment: Bem, eu removi todos os paragrafos, continua na mesma.

Comment: Dá uma olhada então nos comentários do rray na sua pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeHD não foi minha resposta que solucionou sua pergunta. Você poderá votar positivo quando tiver 15 pontos de rep.  O correto é você colocar resolvido na sua própria resposta. Acho que precisa esperar dois dias pra isso ser possível, mas é o correto. Você pode reverter  clicando novamente sob o sinal de resolvido. Sugiro você faça o tour do site, e consulte a Central de Ajuda pra entender como o SOpt funciona. Ah, e seja bem vindo! :)

Comment: Obrigado @gustavox, mais uma vez.

Answer (score 1):

Achei o problema pessoal! Quando resolvi mexer no arquivo acabei esbarrando no meu PHP, apaguei parte da consulta ao banco de dados... dava erro e  redirecionava para a mesma página, porem o POST do form se perdia!. Acabei pensando que o erro era no formulario.... Obrigado!